# Why are the <b> and <i> tags deprecated?

Tags: html, deprecation

This question came up in one of my college classes. The professor only gave the answer that it was more descriptive, but it seems as though `<b>` and `<i>` are rather explicit in their meaning and is easier to type than `<strong>` and `<em>`.

**What were the official arguments for the deprecation of these tags?**

Comment: I'm fairly sure `<b>` and `<i>` aren't deprecated.

Comment: Related reading: [What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271743/289086) along with [<strong> vs <em>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1936864/289086)

Comment: I tend to reason about it like this: Do I want a screen reader to read this differently, or not? If I just want to pick out words to be easy to find by a (non-blind) reader, I might use `b` - it literally means "this is bold", not "this is emphasized". But the main point is, they're different in meaning - there's no deprecation, just a not that when you used to do `b` or `i`, you usually meant `strong` or `em`.

Comment: @MichaelT I remember when I first began using LaTeX, I was confused about all the different ways text could be italicized and bolded on when beginning on a blank document (with no style packages).

Comment: @Luaan: Even if `<i>` and `<b>` aren't actually deprecated, `<tt>` and `<u>` are, and the question would be just as applicable to those.

Comment: @supercat: Actually, `u` isn't deprecated, but given a new meaning.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Fair enough, and it seems the new meaning is consistent with the old one.  The `<tt>` tag seems to no longer work, however.  The `<samp>` tag is probably the safest general-purpose "blind" replacement, though it--like all the other tags--has semantic implications which might not fit all existing uses of `<tt>`.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Last summer, I read the complete HTML5 specification, and every previous HTML specification (even the abandoned ones), and all CSS specs I could find, and a lot of XML specs. Since I love semantically rich hypertext documents, let me give you the idea behind the relevant HTML semantics in HTML5.

## Before HTML5

Before HTML5, `i` and `b` were indeed out of fashion. The reason was that they essentially worked like `em` and `strong`, respectively, but with focus on *presentation* and not on *semantics* (which is bad).

Indeed, `i` meant that the text should be in italics (it said something about how the text should be rendered on-screen). On the other hand, `em` meant that the text was to be emphasised (it said something about the semantics of the text).

There is an important theoretical difference here. If you use `em`, the user agent (=browser) knows the text should be emphasised, so it can render it in italics if the document is displayed on-screen (or all-caps if formatting is not possible, or maybe even in boldface is the user prefers that), it can pronounce it differently if the document is spoken to the user, etc.

Notice that emphasis really is about semantics. For instance, the phrases

- The *cat* is mine. (=not the dog!)
- The cat is *mine*. (=not yours!)

do not have the same meaning.

The same difference applies to `b` (boldface font) and `strong` (strong emphasis).

A general principle of digital writing in general, and of hypertext authoring in particular, is that you should separate content and style. In hypertext authoring, this means that the content should be in the HTML file, and the style should be in a CSS file (or a number of CSS files). A different but related principle is that the document should be rich in semantics (like marking up headers, footers, lists, emphases, addresses, navigational areas, etc.). This has a number of advantages:

- It is much easier for computer programs to interpret the document. These programs include browsers, text-to-speech applications, search engines, and digital assistants. (For example, the browser can let you save an address to your address book, if only it can find and interpret it. Also, you might know that Microsoft Word can create and automatically update a TOC for you if you mark up your headings correctly.)
- It is much easier to change the style later on. (If you want to change the colour of all your third-level headings in your 860-page document, you can change a single line in the stylesheet. If you had mixed content and presentation, you would have to go through the entire document manually. And you would probably miss a heading or two, making the document look unprofessional.)
- You can use different stylesheets depending on the circumstance (is the document being displayed on-screen or printed on paper?). You can even let the end user choose the style herself. (My website offers a number of alternate stylesheets. In IE and FF, you change these using the View menu.)

So, in short, `i` and `b` were deprecated because they were **HTML tags** concerned about **presentation**, which is totally wrong.

## In HTML5

In HTML5 `i` and `b` are no longer deprecated. Instead, *they are given sematic meaning*. So they are now actually about semantics, and not about presentation.

As before, you use `em` to mark up emphasis: "The cat *is* mine." But you use `i` for almost all other cases where you would use italics in a printed work. For instance:

- You use `i` to mark up taxonomic designations: "I like *R. norvegicus*."
- You use `i` to mark up a phrase in a different language compared to the surrounding text: *À la carte*
- You use `i` to mark up a word when you talk about the word itself: "*drink* is both a noun and a verb"

It is also a good idea to use the `class` attribute to specify the precise usage (also Google "microformat" and "microdata"). And, of course, in the second case, you should really use the `lang` attribute to specify the correct language. (Otherwise, **for instance**, a text-to-speech agent might mispronounce the text.)

A year ago or so, the HTML5 specification also said that `cite` should be used to mark up names of books, films, operas, paintings, etc.:

- What do you think of *Nymphomaniac*?

Finally, since long ago, `dfn` is used to mark up the defining instance of a phrase in a text (like a mathematical definition, or the definition of a term):

- A *group* is a set X equipped with a single binary operation * such that...

So the italics in your printed book, which can mean a lot of different things, is represented by four different HTML5 tags, which is really great, because semantics is good, as I tried to convince you about earlier. (For instance, you can ask your browser to make a list of all definitions in the text, so you can make sure you know them all before the exam.)

Turning to `strong` and `b`, the HTML5 specification says that `strong` should be used to mark up an important part of the text, like a warning or some very important-to-catch word in a sentence. On the other hand, `b` should be used to mark up things that need to be easy to find in the text, like keywords. I also use `b` as headings in list items (LIs).

Comment: Correction: the definition tag is [`<dfn>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element), not `<def>`.  Otherwise, great comprehensive summary of all the issues.  Your suggestion to use `<b>` as headings in list items is interesting; the semantic approach is to use a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), but since no browsers currently support `display:run-in`, inline keyword markup with `<b>` or `<span>` are the best you can do.

Comment: @AmeliaBR. Thank you for observing the typo (def). About the definition lists: definition lists should be used for name-value pairs, and I always use them for this (have a look at my [guestbook](http://rejbrand.se/rejbrand/guestbook.asp), for instance). I also loved `display:run-in`, but since its support is *decreasing*, you have to use the `float` or the `content:` trick, see http://rejbrand.se/rejbrand/news.asp?ItemIndex=169. When I talk about using `b` to mark up 'headings' in lists, I do not mean name-value pairs, but rather simple lists where I want to use a 'header' in each item.

Comment: "Before HTML5, `i` and `b` were indeed deprecated." - The `i` and `b` elements have _never_ been "deprecated". In [HTML 4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) they are both valid under a Strict DOCTYPE.

Comment: @w3dk: You are right, I have changed the wording.

Comment: This is a beautiful description and nearly perfectly eliminates any confusion I've had about this change. However, I will say that although a semantic HTML page is important for most applications nowadays, for a writer, *presentation* is oftentimes more important. If I do `<b>`, it's because I need to know that no matter who views my document, they're going to see it as emboldened text. Same thing with `<i>`.

Comment: @SarahofGaia There are at least two flaws with reasoning that `<b>` guarantees emboldened text. 1) Screen readers, braille displays, and other means of consuming text for which thicker glyphs is a meaningless concept. 2) `b { font-weight: normal }`, meaning the display style isn't fixed for `<b>` either.

Comment: Then how could I preserve the style of a text being emboldened no matter what?

Comment: @SarahofGaia: "All" visual browsers make `b`  and `strong` boldface by default; this is in fact recommended in the HTML5 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/single-page.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints (see 10.3.4 Phrasing content). Hence, there is not really any difference at all here (remember: in HTML5, `b` does NOT mean bold). And, of course, all user agents aren't visual, and in either case you should **always** use the semantically right element.

Comment: Finally, you are always free to supply your own CSS if you don't trust the browser: `b, strong { font-weight:bold; }`. That way you can be as sure as you could possibly be. CSS is the way to specify the visual format. HTML is about the meaning (content), CSS about the visual presentation of it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Thanks so much! ^_^ But, I haven't learned extricated CSS yet, only integrated—does one do it that way by `style="font-weight:bold"` or `style="font-weight:strong"` or some other way?

Comment: @SarahofGaia: It's `style="font-weight:bold"`, but you don't want to add that mess to every `strong` element in your 100-page HTML file.

Comment: How would you define a "page" of HTML? I thought HTML is measured in lines, not pages. I mean, as far as I know, there are generally only pages in WYSIWYG editors...

Comment: Also, if I'm going to write a 100-page document, I will generally use a WYSIWYG editor. So I don't think I'll have to worry much about that. Lol.

Comment: This answer gave me the understanding why I need to change my font tags to css. I have always liked font tags bold and all that, now I understand why I shouldn't use them. Thank you

Comment: Why is `strong` a full word, yet `em` is just a substring?

Comment: man... you know how to answer a question!

Comment: Then how can I differentiate between `<mark>` and `<strong>`?

Comment: _because they were HTML tags concerned about presentation, which is totally wrong_ - they were present from the absolutely very beginning, where this was about rendering text better than Gopher could, so you were in the mindset of presenting text on a page, where italics and bold make very much sense.  Then now millions of years later we have found that we would like to think of it in a different way - that doesn't make it totally wrong...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I agree. Words can mean many different things. Of course, the initial designers didn't do anything wrong. But *today*, it is generally considered "totally wrong" to mix content and presentation.

Answer (score 60):

As Doval says, they are not deprecated. They [still exist](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-i-element) but should be used differently from what many people where used to before HTML5.

It's about 'semantic' html. It should describe 'what' it is, instead of how it should look. The browser or theoretically any other display medium (say a reading app for the blind) should be able to decide how exactly  should be interpreted.

This is similar why you should not use CSS class names like "red" and use more descriptive classes that describe the functional idea behind using a different color here. You may later decide that green is better (and maybe anything "strong" should be shown by using red color instead of bold text). Or a color blind user may have some special browser settings where colors are replaced by other means.

Comment: Are there any situations in which it is preferrable to use <b> as opposed to <strong>? Or is <strong> always a "more semantic" tag?

Comment: Roughly you could use <b> for things that should be "highlighted" but not "emphasized", like keywords in a text. In technical documentation you find often different text styles used to show certain attributes, like in programming books code samples or technical terms. For such use cases like a technical term <b> or <i> could be used.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine Take a look at the [official standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-b-element).

Comment: @LanceLaFontaine - equations, see my answer...

Comment: @thorstenmüller I think that's a bad example too... it is the textbook case where management decides later that instead of bold they want their attributes in type-writer font and not bold but underlined, in which case using `<span class="keyword">...</span>` in the first place saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine `<b>` is an edge case, but there are solid examples for using `<i>` for cases where `<em>` is inappropriate: scientific names of species or latin words adopted into English (you *could* use a span with a language attribute, but that has all sorts of other implications -- a screen reader might switch voices for a different language). It can also be used for italicizing titles of other works, although the semantically correct approach is to use `<cite>`.

Comment: @AmeliaBR: Additionally, in cases where the text of a document makes reference to its visual appearance, e.g. referring to "the underlined word", or "the word in blue", there may be some advantage to being able to use style sheets to vary the distance between the underline and the text, or control the exact shade of blue, but one couldn't change the underlined word to red, or the blue word to green, without altering the text that refers to them as being "underlined" or "blue".

Comment: @AmeliaBR A screen reader *should* switch voices for a different language, though.

Comment: @MilesRout: yes, normally.  But not if it is just for a *de facto* or *viz* embedded in an English sentence.  For little words like that, you want the reader to treat them as if they are English words, but many style guides will still suggest that these words should be italicized.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Hence why it's important to distinguish between `<span lang="fr">dérivée partielle</span>` and `<i>de jure</i>`.

Comment: @MilesRout  Exactly.  That's what I was suggesting: cases like this are good uses for `<i>` because you *don't* want the implications of any of the semantic markup options.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: "but should be used differently from what many people where used to before HTML5", but before HTML5 brought them back, they **were** deprecated.

Answer (score 45):

The true story is that `b` and `i` were first obsoleted, deprecated, cursed, and anatematized as “presentational” in various HTML5 drafts (broadly speaking), but then they realized that these tags are widely used and also generated by many authoring programs. Instead of simply allowing them, they developed contrived new “semantic” definitions for them, to be able to allow the elements but still pretend to be strict about “presentational” markup. The new definitions have varied from one draft to another and are obscure: you can hardly find two people who understand and interpret them the same way.

Sorry, no references. The description above is a result of following the changes and reading the drafts and discussions, often between the lines. They are not explicitly telling the cause. I still think it’s the true story.

The conclusion is: Move on. There’s nothing useful here. The `b` and `i` elements do the same thing as they always have: they make the font bold or italic, respectively, with the usual caveats. This is the reality that you should take into account, not the quasischolastic “semantics” that has no impact on browsers, search engines, or other software.

Comment: That said, you can follow the quasischolastic semantics just by treating `<b>` as a funny kind of `<span>` that *by default* renders in bold. Then if you can be bothered, give your uses of it a `class` attribute too so that when necessary you can restyle multiple things at once that used it because they have common semantics. It's quasischolastic in the sense that people will think you're quasi in the head for doing `b.productname {font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; }` after you changed your mind about presentation and took advantage of your wise choice of semantic markup ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: For those few of us in the world who still care about file size, saying `<b>this</b>` seems much more reasonable than `<span class="bold">this</b>` (the eight-byte overhead of the former is irksome enough; the 23-byte overhead of the latter seems crazy).  I wonder why HTML never defined any short-form representation like `<@quack>this</@>` as equivalent to `<span class="quack">this</span>`?

Comment: @supercat: that's what transfer-encoding: gzip is for. Or maybe XML+XSLT, depending exactly where and how you want to introduce a more concise notation for "quack".

Comment: @supercat developer productivity costs more than bandwidth.  I suspect the time it takes to send the extra bytes over the network is negligible, especially when considering the overhead of creating the actual output (database calls, network sockets, javascript files, etc.)

Comment: The overhead matters a little for mobile browsers on slower networks

Comment: @SteveJessop: My question about why nothing better was introduced relates to the fact that these standards were developed at a time when 14.4k dialup connections were still pretty common and transfer-encoding: gzip was not yet available.  On a 14.4k connection, the extra time to render a dense table which uses styles in semantically-meaningful fashion could be significant.

Comment: @supercat **`class='bold'`?** Master Suku of [The Codeless Code](http://thecodelesscode.com) would have words with you about [the use of such poor classnames](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/95). Consider this your last *boldRedText*.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: My question is why, in the days of 14.4K modems, there wasn't a concise way of specifying a class.  Compared to other markup formats, the 7-bytes of overhead of `<b>text</b>` was already bad enough.  Why should defining a class add an extra nine bytes in addition to the class name?  Besides, given that a "bold" that appears within a "MainBody" element can be handled arbitrarily differently from one that appears within a "SideBar" element, the requirement isn't that names be globally unique, but rather that a nested set of styles contains a unique name somewhere in it.

Comment: You can extend this argument: why do we have <p>, <h1> through <h6>, <hr>, <abbr> ? Because it was seen that some fundamental patterns of writing are so common that it is useful to have a 'built-in' way of marking them up and giving them a default style. Of course HTML could have defined only <body> <div> and <span> and provided no default styling at all, but (I believe) very few authors would have adopted it as they would be forever having to provide basic semantics and styling that is common to the vast majority of documents.

Comment: I disagree with this answer and don't understand how it got this many upvotes.. The accepted answer explains exactly why <b> and <strong>/<i> and <em> are not the same (speech, accessibility - what vs how it should look)..

Comment: In the days of 14.4 modems, CSS was an _idea_ not yet realized or implemented in any user agent. These HTML elements are merely ancient legacy cruft we'll be stuck with forever.

Comment: @supercat Seems like "strong" would probably work.

Comment: @Tsasken Yes, but b and i are not deprecated and this answer is right as far as the new definitions being totally contrived.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: During the time CSS was being developed, 28.8K modems existed but had not yet become mainstream, and even at 28.8K page load times were definitely longer than ideal.  I think it would have been obvious that allowing e.g. `<td !q>` as a synonym for `<td style="q">` would improve load times (and also make things nicer for people hand-coding HTML) without hurting expressiveness.

Comment: @supercat Yes, it's obvious that would save space, but nobody was really concerned much with load times back then, since everything took so long to load anyway. People who didn't live in an area where DSL or cable were just becoming available had no choice but to wait. Page load time wasn't much of a concern until what we think of as broadband became much more widespread.

Comment: @Tsasken, the question was why `b` and `i` got “deprecated”, not how they differ from something else.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: You don't think people noticed when some pages took two seconds to load and others took ten, and preferred the ones that only took two?  Some people may not have cared about users' page load times, but some people (including, but not limited to, the users) definitely did.

Comment: @supercat Not when it was considered normal for a page to take 10 to 30 seconds to load! And Gawd help you if you hadn't gotten a new modem. I was browsing the web at _2400 baud_ in the early days.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I had a tape drive for my Commodore 64, and later "upgraded" to a 1541 floppy, so I know what "slow" is.  Still, the fact that people were willing to wait for things to load doesn't mean they liked it, and wouldn't have much preferred them to be faster.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's definitely false; the recommendations for page load times have stayed pretty consistent and I remember dire warnings, in the old days, to stay away from animated GIFs and too many images.

Comment: @supercat "I think it would have been obvious that allowing e.g. <td !q> as a synonym for <td style="q"> would improve load times" - this is hardly obvious or even true. Such things are really not relevant in determing load times - things like use of images, other media or some unoptimized, tool-generated HTML are, as well as arranging for blocking vs non-blocking download of resources. That's where the actual, noticeable difference is, not if HTML contains a few more characters or not.

Comment: This is obviously the truth. Most people don't realize that at first the WHATWG nonsense was just about dismissed out of hand by the W3C, and then after some power struggles they came out on top and got themselves a W3C approved spec.

Answer (score 12):

The `<b>` and `<i>` tags originated with the concepts of "bold" and "italic".  The problem is these may be completely meaningless for some user agents.  For instance, what does "italic" sound like in a screen reader for a blind person?

Replacing them with `<strong>` and `<em>` removed the direct link to typographical concepts.  Instead, the user agent can render them however it sees fit.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the user agent can render `<b>` and `<i>` however it sees fit, too.

Comment: You're repeating aspirational information not practical information. If user agents don't acknowledge b and i tags then they don't acknowledge strong and em tags. More of the web uses b and i tags than strong and em so if a screen reader only supports strong and em they are not a practical screen reader.

Answer (score 9):

The `<b>` and `<i>` tags are essential when you literally require text in 'bold' or 'italic'.

If you're writing an equation in HTML where an italicised '*I* ' has a different meaning from a non-italicised 'I' it's important to be able to make that distinction.

I think of them in the same way I think of `<sup>` or `<sub>` tags - you can't correctly represent the meaning of an equation without using such 'appearance' tags.

The purist approach would be to use MathML or TeX but browser support isn't there yet...

Comment: I wish the people pushing for "semantic" markup would recognize that in some cases the old tags were more *semantically correct* than any alternatives.  If the text of a document makes reference to certain underlined words, then showing those words in any fashion other than by underlining them would be semantically wrong.  If one is importing text from a system which puts some of it `in a monospaced typeface` but which makes no distinction as to why, then using one of the "replacements" for `<tt>` would falsely imply that the code doing the import knew more than it did about the purpose.

Comment: I agree with the suitability of `b` and `i` in mathematical (and physical) contexts, but such usage is *not* mentioned in HTML5 drafts. When I raised this question, it was seriously responded that the Unicode special characters (mathematical bold letters and mathematical italic letters) be used instead!

Comment: @supercat: the general claim (which I admit is not always applicable) is that you shouldn't write cheques that the user-agent can't cash. In particular you shouldn't write a page that claims somebody's screen-reader will speak in a monospaced font (I imagine a robot-voice would be appropriate: I've never actually used a screen reader). Of course this ignores that most people's pages don't work on screen-readers in the least, and so there's no point them paying any price for a hypothetical accessibility they don't care about. But W3C *deliberately* neglects that fact as a matter of principle.

Comment: In the case of the code import, I suppose the canonical (if unsatisfactory) answer is `class="source-X-asserts-it-should-be-monospace"`, thus distinguishing it from text that is semantically different in the sense that some *other* source asserts for unknown reasons that it should be monospace. In effect this is auditing the stuff that HTML considers bad, instead of merely translating the badness into the HTML.

Comment: @SteveJessop: In other words, we should improve `<TT>`, which directly suggested that text should be set in a contrasting monospace font, with markup which, after a few layers of indirection, will indicate that text should be shown in some particular font which happens to be monospace.  While I would not expect all screen readers to do something useful with `<tt>`, I would expect they'd have a much easier time with `<tt>` than `<span class="styleNameThisImportUtilityPicked">`.

Comment: @supercat: sort of, the point being that the layers of indirection provide an opportunity for you to do something sensible with the representation that *may or may not* be the same for all the different reasons it ended up monospace, should you ever figure any of them out. If you import everything into just `<tt>` then you've lost the distinction. Of course if you're translating on the fly rather than importing once then you can be more cavalier about discarding information, because of... the extra layer of indirection introduced by the translation process!

Comment: @SteveJessop: IMHO, if style sheets are supposed to be about presentation and not semantics, it should be possible to extract all of the semantic information in a document without having to examine any of the styles.  Requiring semantically-significant aspects of a document's formatting to be handled via style sheets is IMHO a step backward in that regard.

Comment: @supercat: what aspect of the semantics of your hypothetical scenario, do you feel is not reflected by `class="source-X-asserts-it-should-be-monospace"` and is instead handled in the style sheets? I picked the name pretty much just to restate what you said about the content. Note that if you have no need otherwise to use CSS for this document then there's nothing to stop you doing `<tt class="that-monstrous-long-name">`, and only adding a style sheet if and when you need one. I'm not saying HTML+CSS is perfect, mind, merely that it contains a working solution to these particular scenarios.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Suppose a browser is running on a text-based terminal which supports a moderate number of display attributes, and it sees `<span class="someUnfamiliarName">`.  How should the browser know what that means?  I would posit that it's useful to have tags defined with reasonable default meanings such that applying those meanings and ignoring style attributes would yield a document which, while not pretty, was at least semantically correct.  Also, if all `<TT>` tags in an area would have the same meaning, what advantage is there of `<tt class="foo">` every time versus surrounding the...

Comment: ...area with `<div class="ttMeansFoo">`?  Semantically, I think `<tt class="someName">` would be fine, but `<tt>` is no longer considered acceptable and, as noted, there's no guarantee that the way in which user agents would render the replacements would be suitable for all cases where `<tt>` would have been used in the past.

Comment: @supercat: the simple answer is that user agents *don't* understand user-defined semantics, and don't need to. This doesn't mean that languages in which users can and should define semantics are defective. The user agent knows how to present the data (because the CSS provides the presentation), and the semantic identifiers supply hooks for alternative presentations and semantic analysis (by anyone who knows what Foo means) as required. I don't know the official word on `<div class="ttMeansFoo">` containing `<tt>`, but to me that seems legit, since it gives CSS, xpath etc just as good a hook.

Comment: ... however, it might be *unwise* for much the same reason that shadowing a frequently-used global identifier in a scope in C++ might be unwise. But to me the problem is purely about the pragmatic details of writing and maintaining the HTML. Using "`<tt>` inside `<div class="ttMeansFoo">`" exclusively with some specific meaning is indeed semantic markup, and to say "always give every `<tt>` element a `class` attribute", if anyone does say that, is a simplification. I may be heterodox in this matter, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop: My point with `ttMeansFoo` is that one wishes to combine on a single page a document where things marked `<tt>` should look like keyboard keys, and another where `<tt>` should look like code, enclosing each document in a `div` whose class indicates what the `<tt>` should mean would then allow user agents that can parse the styles to make the distinction, while simultaneously allowing user agents that can't pass the styles to show `<tt>` content in a fashion distinct from other tags.  BTW, the OCR example wasn't great--a better one would be existing HTML content which uses TT.

Comment: @SteveJessop: If a forum has historically white-listed `<tt>` as a form of markup, what should newer versions of the forum do with text that was marked in that fashion?  Arguably, some should be changed to `<kbd>` and some to `<code>`, but if the forum has no way of knowing which would be better for part of a message, I would posit that if `<tt>` was still valid it would be less likely to be misinterpreted than anything else the forum software might do.

Comment: `The <b> and <i> tags are essential when you literally require text in 'bold' or 'italic'.` with the caveat that you only *literally* get that if somebody hasn't stuck in a style sheet with, for example `b { font-weight: normal }`. Of course, anybody who did such a thing should probably be beaten.

Comment: @MattBurland: I would think something like `b { font-family: FonzoDark; font-weight:normal }` could be reasonable if the body copy is in a font which lacks a decent bold but would fit better with "FonzoDark-regular" than with "FonzoDark-bold".  A speech synthesizer which pronounces `<b>` tags differently from other text would have no trouble making clear what text was emboldened; I'm not sure how the document could particularly well handle things if `FonzoDark-regular` was unavailable, but a speech synthesizer shouldn't care.

Comment: @supercat: plausible use-case of `<tt>`, but now you're in effect asking what to do with legacy HTML in light of modern advice. And in fact if it's from a BB that filters tags, legacy HTML written using an under-featured subset even of the version of the standard it was originally written to. I don't think it's a major defect in HTML if what you do with that ends up requiring a choice between (a) something that is no longer recommended when writing new HTML or (b) something ungainly such as marking it up with `<tt class="legacy-forum-data">` or `<div class="legacy-forum-data"> ... <tt>`

Comment: @SteveJessop: The `<tt>` tag is deprecated.  If it goes away, `<tt class="whatever">` won't work, and if it doesn't go away, one can simply define a style for `tt` tags that appear within a `div` of class "UserPosting", without any need to clutter up the `tt` tag with a class specification.

Comment: In any case, I guess my main thought is that it's helpful to have "simple" markup tags which would allow a user agent with limited abilities to indicate semantically-significant markup while filtering out presentation markup.  If a screen reader's most pleasant voice is assigned to "normal" text, things which should cause it to use another voice should be marked up with some sort of tag, while those which would use italic because a certain font's italic face is prettier than its normal face should be marked with a <div> class.  Within reason, the more kinds of tags there are, the better.

Answer (score 1):

The design principles underlying the HTML tags is that they should be "semantic" i.e. they should indicate meaning and intent rather than low level instruction.

The classic test is "can the tags be meaningfully used in a browser for the blind".

So for an audio based browser the "i" for italic is pretty useless as you cannot have italic speech. However the "em" tag is meaningful as an audio device can emphasize a phrase in many ways: by raising pitch, increasing volume or changing accent. A Braille renderer could emphasize by raising the dots changing spacing, changing size  or adding vibration.

Comment: As you say you can't have italic speech - but you can have italic text where the fact it is italic has semantic meaning, eg equations...

Comment: *'So for an audio based browser the "i" for italic is pretty useless as you cannot have italic speech.'* ... Yes, and so is `<img>` because you can't speak an image, and a system without sound hardware can't present `<audio>`. Sometimes presentation is the very purpose of an element, and it doesn't need to be universally supported (and unlike other potentially unsupported elements, `<i>` doesn't need alt text because the fact that it's italic is the only information lost). The real problem is when people say `i` when they *mean* `em`.

Comment: @SAL: Why can't one have "italic speech"?  If normal speech is spoken with a "pitch" value of 100, having text within an `<i>` tag use pitch of 120 and text within a `<b>` tag use 80, and having text within a `<tt>` synchronize the speech with a synthesized typewriter producing the text would allow the listener to readily distinguish those forms of markup.  The job would be much harder if instead of using an `<i>` tag the text instead used a `<span class="whatever">` which caused parts of the text to be shown using "Acme SemiScript" rather than "Waldorf Sans" [some font families...

Comment: ...don't have a good italic font, but sometimes an italic-only font may look good when set within text written using another font family].

Comment: @supercat You're describing emphasized speech, not italic speech. If you want a different tone then you should use em, like nmclean said. If you want it italicized, use i. It doesn't matter that a screen reader doesn't know what to do, because there's nothing for it to do. Book titles are often italicized, but you don't pronounce them any differently.

Comment: @DCShannon: Is there any reason a text-to-speech utility couldn't audibly distinguish all of the markup tags from each other?  Using a somewhat different voice for the content of `<i>` tags would seem like it would be useful in some cases, and nearly always harmless in any event.  Humans may pronounce things like titles the same as the surrounding text in cases where it would not cause ambiguity, but would generally alter the pronunciation or prosody when necessary to prevent confusion.  Since a text-to-speech utility won't know what will or won't be confusing, having it always adjust...

Comment: ...pronunciation would seem safer than having it try to guess whether that was necessary.  Note that the adjusted pronunciation of titles, foreign words, mathematical variable names, etc. should probably be different from the pronunciation of things which are *important*.  The latter should use `<em>`, while the former things should not.

Comment: @supercat. I'm making the case where italic does NOT mean emphasis.  It means nothing other than italic.  I reckon that in my example of equations a speech reader should say "Italic uppercase I" as each of those terms ('italic', 'uppercase' and 'I') carries semantic meaning.  Miss out any one and you've changed the _meaning_  of the symbol.  But I appreciate that ain't gonna happen without some wrapper <eqn> tag or similar...

Comment: @SAL: Italic text needs to be rendered in a fashion which indicates that it is different from roman text; if the operator of a text reader configures it so that normal text should sound like Homer Simpson, but `<i>`-tagged text sounds like Marge, and in either voice uppercase letters are shouted and lowercase letters are whispered, the use of those particular voices wouldn't be semantically meaningful to most people, but would be meaningful to the operator who selected them.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML5 is not meant for styling of web page.

The bold and italic tags are purely decorative, when we moved towards HTML5 there was a great emphasis on semantically meaningful tags. That is to say tags that are not purely decorative, but give meaning to the web-page, meaning that the google-bot can, for instance, parse and understand.

The discipline of semantics is very important in HTML, but unlike the regular philosophical inquiry of semantics, HTML is concerned with the semantics of which a computer understands.